# Twilio Gather Delay

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-twiml

I noticed a huge delay in playing the PLAY tags inside GATHER tags, it has a delay for more than 8 - 11 seconds. But if I remove the  tag the delay is less than 6 seconds?  How can I reduce the delay?

Here is the sample Twiml with a delay of more than 11 seconds

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather numDigits="1" method="POST" actionOnEmptyResult="false" timeout="10" action="https://samplemyaudiohook.com/">
        <Play>https://sampleaudio.com/test.wav</Play>
        <Play>https://sampleaudio.com/test2.wav</Play>
    </Gather>
    <Say voice="alice">Sorry, we didnt get any response.  Good bye and thank you for calling.</Say>
</Response>
```

Here is a sample twiml with only 6 seconds or less delay

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
        <Play>https://sampleaudio.com/test.wav</Play>
        <Play>https://sampleaudio.com/test2.wav</Play>
</Response>
```

Comment: Is there a specific question? Where are you hosting your assets and what are their size? You can use request inspector to analyze the details. https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136407-Debugging-your-application

Comment: hi @Alan, Sorry, I updated my question. my main question is how I can reduce the delay? I got Etag and Last-modified header already set on the audio URLs so it should cache the audio the second time around. And I have no errors on Twilio debugger. Still, there is a huge difference between the delay between the two Twiml.

Comment: Try narrowing down the issue. Can you try hosting the Assets on Twilio assets to see if the issue is on your infrastructure side? https://www.twilio.com/console/functions/overview